# Resetting a submitted form in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, variables

I'm mapping some data coming from the remote source into my entites. I'm using forms for this purpose. Here is a fragment of code that is responsible for mapping data onto entities:

```
    $i = 0;
    $x = 0;
    foreach ($bestellerLists[0] as $bestsellerList) {
        $List[$i] = new BestsellerList();
        foreach ($bestsellerList['books'] as $book) {
            $Book = new Book();
            $bookForm = $this->bookForm;
            $bookForm->setData($Book);
            $bookForm->submit($book);
            $List[$i]->addBook($Book);
            unset($bookForm);
            unset($Book);
            $x = $x + 1;
        }
        $i = $i+ 1;
    }
```

The problem that I cannot solve is that in the first iteration if the inner `foreach` loop, everything is well, entities get mapped, the first `$Book` is added to the current `$List`.

However, the second interation of the inner loop errors out with:

> You cannot change the data of a submitted form.

As you can see, the `$bookForm` is assigned the value with `$bookForm = $this->bookForm`. At the end of the current iteration I `unset` `$bookForm` in order to create a new one at the next iteration.

I really do not get why Symfony would complain about changing the data of a submitted form. A new empty form should be used at each iteration. Any idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: Seems to me that, in this case, you're using `FormType` for validation only, right?

Comment: @JovanPerovic Indeed, data validation will be added to it later on. Another benefit is that I do not have to manually call all the setters on my entities when using forms.

Comment: You need to create a new form for each iteration as it keeps track of whether it has been submitted or not, so as to not be submitted twice. How you would go about this depends on how you generate your form. You might even be able to do a `$bookForm = clone($this->bookForm)` to create a new instance but I've never tried it so I'm not too sure.

Comment: @Qoop `$bookForm = clone($this->bookForm)` and then `unset($bookForm)` does the job..too an extent... After several iterations the program errors out with "OutOfMemory" Exception. I'm wondering what is consuming so much memory in this loop. The cloned object gets unset, the input data is not large at all.

Comment: On each iteration `$Book` is being added to `$List` so that is growing. Also garbage collection doesn't happen immediately, it just kind of happens when it happens. If you are planning on adding these to a db, why not add each book per iteration (or 10, or 50, or what ever) and then check for the presence of a book ( and update/add as necessary) and then clear the manager. Another thing may be due to using things in `dev` (if you are) as this environment does a lot of logging so kills a lot of memory.